# Django app: on modelse.py any kind of def is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

here my code, last two function is not working i am also trying more function but still they are not working.

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # nothing to show


def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def snippet(self):
    return self.body[0:50]
```

Comment: Those functions should be inside not class, not outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks  MD. Khairul Basar its working now. Thanks a Lot